# How do you backup 340GB worth of pictures?

Tags: backup, photos

It's around 10 years worth of pictures so what's the best way to backup that? If I would upload it to the cloud (would that be S3, Glacier or some other cloud storage) with my 2.5MBit upload, it would take around 14 days non-stop, which isn't very feasible. It has to be an off-site backup, since I already have a NAS backup solution. I thought about copying it to an external harddisk and leave it at my parents house but is this really the best off-site solution?

Comment: "2.5MBit upload" - From my experience I've never been able to get anywhere near that kind of upload speed with the cloud backup services I've tried. (I've been rather disappointed!) I have a 3.2Mbps upload. YMMV.

Comment: Have you even looked at cloud storage providers? You can seed with a physical hard drive http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/feature/seed_service#seed_your_initial_backup_to_crashplan_central

Comment: " I thought about copying it to an external harddisk and leave it at my parents house but is this really the best off-site solution?" YES

Comment: This is the solution I use for my pictures. Every year both of us back up to a HDD, and then we swap HDD. Should the HDD get lost or damaged in transport then we still have a year old backup.

Comment: @Hennes: "Every year" ?!

Comment: Yes, my offsite backup is only yearly. My local backups are more up to date, but the HDD swap and my parents backup only happen at the end of each year.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not the answer you are looking for but regular small uploads to the cloud is the way to go. Obviously this doesn't solve your current problem but it is surely what you should do going forward.

As you already have a nas backup I don't see anything wrong with keeping a HDD backup at you parents as it does provide a more secure backup. Just remember to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Secondary backup drives that are physically shipped elsewhere is a good method.
I think there are backup providers for doing this too -- though, I don't have any references off-hand.
<sup>This is provided to specifically counter the insane upload times you refer.</sup>

Personally, I'd just keep a secondary backup elsewhere -- your option of parent's house sounds quite resilient.

Think a little more on how you will maintain this 'off-site' backup as you keep adding files to your NAS.

1. Incremental copies that you will carry off-site to sync the secondary.
2. network connection at the secondary to `rsync` the secondary once in a while

But, do keep the secondary off-line for all other times to reduce risk.